# Could someone create a [gitlab] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have posted [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104015/how-to-configure-a-default-readme-in-gitlab) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104017/128573) question. These are about GitLab, not GitHub.

Could someone create a [gitlab](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gitlab) tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done: [gitlab](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gitlab)

It needs an excerpt and wiki, of course.